I don't get how the “edge angle” node works
I'm trying to figure out how the “edge angle” node works: I can't get the right angle on the right line, there's always an offset and I can't figure out where my mistake is.
In the attached example, angles 116° and 63° are inverted.

the scene:


(Using Blender 3.6.12)
The Edge Angle node is computing the angle at an edge as the angle between the normal of its adjacent faces, not as the angle delimited by both faces.
Consequently in the following figure displaying the normals in Edit Mode, for the bottom left corner (in red) the value is higher than 90° while the mesh exhibits an obtuse angle. For the top left corner (in blue), the mesh exhibits an open angle, while the angle between normals is lower than 90°.

A bit of mathematics... (in green) Because the sum of angles in a quadrilateral is 360°, and that normals are making obviously an angle of 90° with the faces, it remains that the angle $\alpha$ is 180° minus the angle between the normals, as in Gorgious's answer.

Here's a confirmation that it's based on normals (converted the quad to hexagon by subdividing long edges, moving a vertex not affecting the surface near the edge): https://i.imgur.com/bwXtUa3.gif The way I intuitively think of angles is how much the "face flow" rotates: https://i.imgur.com/lPY73rJ.png so when faces are coplanar, there's "no angle", rather than 180°, and that's where the need to subtract from 180° comes from. So the green dotted arc marks the angle reported: https://i.imgur.com/C7k0J7Q.png

You need to subtract these angles from 180° to get the value you're looking for. The actual maths behind it go a bit over my head but that seemed like a straightforward solution. BTW I don't think the sample index here is necessary.


The solution is indeed simple even if I don't understand why we don't have the angle directly.
Thanks for the solution (and also for using the modulo node, I wouldn't have thought of it :) )

@Humfred You don't have the angle "directly", because it is based on the face normals - let's assume you only have for example just two faces with one edge between them, where it is not so obvious (at least to humans) what is "inside" and what might be the angles you're interested in. Then Blender needs a rule which angle to calculate, therefore the normals are relevant. If you would flip the faces, you would get the angle directly.
